# Vimeo API: Is there a way to download a version of one of your videos?

Tags: api, vimeo, offline-caching

I was hoping to have a way to take videos uploaded via the API that were transcoded and to essentially pick a quality level or file format and download the resulting video to a local device. Essentially this would be a way to download a video for offline use. Is this possible with the Vimeo API at all (I've got a Pro/Business account)? I have a URL from the upload process which I can use with the oEmbed player but the oEmbed process requires an internet connection.

Answer (score 1):

Vimeo's (in beta) API3 offers some of this functionality to PLUS/PRO accounts. You can request access at https://vimeo.com/help/contact

Comment: I actually have access to that but the documentation is pretty meager at this point. I have access to the doc (I think the one you posted?) but it's just a list of endpoints and there's nothing about downloading (at least nothing showing any params I can send in to specify a format and a non-streaming download...). Is there new documentation out there now?

Comment: One of the documents is a list of all of the expected api responses. Included in this list should be the video files you are looking for. Keep in mind, your play stats will be inaccurate if you use video file URLS in this way.

Comment: Which doc is this? I've got the one listing the endpoints and the "getting started" one that runs through the various bits.

Comment: "Getting Started" step 2 links to all of the docs, one of which is "Responses"

Comment: Maybe we're talking about two different things. I guess these docs are searchable so I don't need to hide them as I thought I did. I'm talking about these: https://developer.vimeo.com/api/docs/spec and https://developer.vimeo.com/api/docs/endpoints. Though I grew a brain cell and tried this and got the responses doc I think you're talking about: https://developer.vimeo.com/api/docs/responses. Are you referring to the "files" node under the "videos" response? Would "link" usually be populated?

Comment: Correct, link is left out of the docs for security reasons, and a fake url will be added down the line.